# Laravel Eloquant editing model with one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a `Student` model and a `Subject` model. A student can take many subjects, so there is a `StudentSubject` model as well.
In an HTML page I let the user select the Subjects for a given Student using check-boxes.

On this page a certain user can de-select some existing subjects and add new subjects. Is there an easy way in Laravel/Eloquant to remove the removed ones and add the newly added ones? Or do I have to manually compare the existing database records and the data posted by the user to identify which were newly added and which were removed?

PS:- The above is a `many to many` relationship. I would like to know if there is a way for 'one to many' relationships as well. For example, `Student`, and `PhoneNumber`(A Student can have multiple phone numbers)

Comment: Yes there is a `sync` method for doing this, but you will have to create relationship like Student belongsToMany and Subject belongsToMany relationships for using that method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sync`.

See "Syncing For Convenience" in the official documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships